# What topological group is $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

The integers $\mathbb Z$ are a normal subgroup of $(\mathbb R, +)$. The quotient $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is a familiar topological group; what is it?

I've found elsewhere on the internet that it is the same as the topological group $(S^1, *)$ but have no idea how to show this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some work here's my answer.

Begin with: 
$$\phi:\Bbb R\to S^1\le\Bbb C^*\;,\;\;\phi(r):=e^{2\pi i r}$$

Then we want to show that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and $S^1$.

Note: By Euler's formula, $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$.

First we prove that $\phi$ is surjective. This is easy to see since from our note $\sin$ and $\cos$ must span all possible values of a and b to give norm 1.

Again from our note it is clear that $\phi$ maps all integers to 1, the identity element of $S^1$. This is precisely $\ker(\phi)$.

Thus, by the first isomorphism theorem we have $(S^1, *)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb R / \Bbb Z$.

Comment: If I understand your post correctly, you have found a *group isomorphism* between $S^1$ and $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. (The same was also shown in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/565623/8297).) Since you are interested in topological groups, you should also show that this map is a homeomorphism. This post might be interesting for you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415735/first-isomorphism-theorem-for-topological-groups

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Define

$$\phi:\Bbb R\to S^1\le\Bbb C^*\;,\;\;\phi(r):=e^{2\pi i r}$$

Comment: So if I prove this map is an isomorphism then I am done?

Comment: This map induces a continuous map $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S^1$ which is a bijection. You then need to show that the inverse is continuous.

Comment: Perhaps, but you won't: it is NOT an isomorphism, only an epimorphism.

Comment: @BrianKlatt, are you sure the OP wants the topological groups thing? I thought it was mainly a group theory question, though it is tagged also as "general-topology"

Comment: @DonAntonio I recognize the wording of the question from Munkres' book so I immediately went into topology mode.

Comment: Oh, I see @BrianKlatt...hehe. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is indeed from Munkres, okay I'll try to work through this thanks!