# Can the FHHF theorem be proved using the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, alternative-proof, abelian-categories

The FHHF theorem, stated in Vakil’s FOAG(The Rising Sea: Foundations Of Algebraic Geometry Notes, [see here for the available electronic versions](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/)), is as follows:

> 1.6.I. IMPORTANT EXERCISE (THE FHHF THEOREM). This result can take you far, and perhaps for that reason it has sometimes been called the Fernbahnhof (FernbaHnHoF) Theorem, notably in [Vak1, Exer. 1.6.I]. Suppose F: $\mathscr{A} \rightarrow \mathscr{B}$ is a covariant functor of abelian categories, and $\mathrm{C}^{\bullet}$ is a complex in $\mathscr{A}$. Show that
>
> (a) ( $\mathrm{F}$ right-exact yields $\mathrm{FH}^{\bullet} \longrightarrow \mathrm{H}^{\bullet} \mathrm{F}$ ) If $\mathrm{F}$ is right-exact, describe a natural morphism $\mathrm{FH}^{\bullet} \rightarrow \mathrm{H}^{\bullet} \mathrm{F}$. (More precisely, for each $i$, the left side is $F$ applied to the cohomology at piece $i$ of $\mathrm{C}^{\bullet}$, while the right side is the cohomology at piece $i$ of $\mathrm{FC}^{\bullet}$.
>
> (b) (F left-exact yields $\mathrm{FH}^{\bullet} \longleftarrow \mathrm{H}^{\bullet} \mathrm{F}$ ) If $\mathrm{F}$ is left-exact, describe a natural morphism $\mathrm{H}^{\bullet} \mathrm{F} \rightarrow \mathrm{FH}^{\bullet}$.
>
> (c) (F exact yields $\mathrm{FH}^{\bullet} \stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow} \mathrm{H}^{\bullet} \mathrm{F}$ ) If $\mathrm{F}$ is exact, show that the morphisms of (a) and (b) are inverses and thus isomorphisms.

The abstract nonsense way to do it is as in the thread [Prove the FHHF theorem using as much abstract non-sense as possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541104/prove-the-fhhf-theorem-using-as-much-abstract-non-sense-as-possible)

Can it be proved using the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem? I took two embeddings taking $\mathscr{A}, \mathscr{B}$ into categories of $R$ and $S$ modules respectively. But it seems that the functor $F$ cannot be some kind “transferred”.

The main reason I wanna to do this is trying to gain some practice in the embedding theorem.

Thank you in advanced for any help.

Comment: Would you mind giving complete bibliographic entry for Vak1 and FOAG?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yeah I added a link to the home page. And [Vak1] is just the self reference to the same exercise, it’s some kind of a cold joke I think though irrelevant to the question…