# Why is the category of finitely generated modules over a non-noetherian ring not abelian?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, additive-categories

I am learning about abelian categories for a talk I have to give next week. One of the first questions I had upon learning this definition is "does there exist an additive category that is not abelian?"

The question, 
[Additive category that is not abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001/additive-category-that-is-not-abelian),
gives many great answers to the question but I am curious about the details, in particular about the example of finitely generated modules over a non-noetherian ring.

The definition I am using for abelian categories is as followed:

> A category $\mathcal{C}$ is abelian if
>
> 1) $\mathcal{C}$ is an additive category
>
> 2) Every morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ has a kernel and cokernel
>
> 3) Every monomorphism is the kernel of a map, and every epimorphism is a cokernel of a map.

Thus my question is:

> Given the above definition of abelian categories,
>   why is the category of finitely-generated modules over a non-noetherian ring not abelian?

My guess would be that this could fail because some kernels/cokernels might not be finitely generated, but I am blanking on how to construct an example.

Comment: Kernels are problematic: Let $R$ be a non-Noetherian ring.  Let $I$ be ideal, which is not finitely generated (this exists because $R$ is not Noetherian). $I$ now is the kernel of $R\to R/I$. Also both $R$ and $R/I$ are finitely generated as $R$-modules (by 1 actually). Hence the kernel, in the category of finitely generated $R$-modules, does not always exist.

Comment: This helps, thank you very much! I am going to write down the extra details I needed to check for myself in case someone else has the same question. This works because  a) one of the equivalent definitions of a noetherian ring is that every ideal is finitely generated (therefore in $R$ there exists an $I$ not finitely generated) and b)modules over a ring are finitely generated iff they are a quotient of $R^n$, which $R/I$ clearly is.

Comment: @Hamed One has to consider the possibility that kernels of f.g modules could a priori differ from those computed in the category of _all_ modules.

Comment: @Hanno you're absolutely right. I wanted to mention this myself but it was already along comment (Thankfully now you provided the answer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **Claim:** The inclusion $R\text{-mod}\hookrightarrow R\text{-Mod}$ preserves kernels.

Once this is known, it follows that a kernel in $R\text{-mod}$, if it exists, must be isomorphic to the corresponding kernel in $R\text{-Mod}$; in particular, the latter is finitely generated.

Specializing this observation to projections $\pi_I: R\to R/I$ for an ideal $I$ in $R$, it follows that $\ker(\pi_I)$ exists in $R\text{-mod}$ if and only if $I$ is finitely generated. Letting $I$ vary, we see that $R\text{-mod}$ is abelian only if all ideals of $R$ are finitely generated.

*Proof of claim:* Suppose $f: M\to N$ is a morphism of finitely generated $R$-modules and $k: K\to M$ is a kernel of $f$ in $R\text{-mod}$. Further, let $g: T\to M$ be another $R$-module homomorphism with $fg=0$ and $T$ *arbitrary*. Then, by assumption, for any finitely generated submodule $\iota: S\subseteq T$ the composite $g\iota$ factors uniquely through $k$ via some $t_S: S\to K$. Since any module is the union of its finitely generated submodules, it follows that a factorization of $g$ through $k$ is unique, if it exists. In turn, applying this uniqueness it moreover follows that for any other $\iota^{\prime}: S^{\prime}\subseteq T$, the factorizations $S\to K$ and $S^{\prime}\to K$ of $\iota$ resp. $\iota^{\prime}$ agree on $S\cap S^{\prime}$. Therefore, all $t_S$ glue to a factorization $t: T\to K$ of $g$ through $k$, proving that $k$ is a kernel in $R\text{-Mod}$.

**Addendum** *(independent of the rest)*: If you like it more technically, you can package the same argument as follows: Consider any category ${\mathscr C}$ (generalizing $R\text{-Mod}$), any diagram $D: I\to {\mathscr C}$ over some index category $I$ (generalizing $\bullet\rightrightarrows\bullet$), and any cone $c: D\to X$ over it, that is, you have $X\in{\mathscr C}$ and for any $i\in I$ you have a morphism $c_i: X\to D(i)$ such that $$X\xrightarrow{c_i} D(i)\xrightarrow{D(\alpha)} D(j) = X\xrightarrow{c_j} D(j)$$ for any arrow $\alpha$ in $I$. In other words, $X\to D$ is a *candidate* for a limit-cone for $I$, and you might ask:

> *Question:* Which objects of ${\mathscr C}$ indeed 'see' $X$ as the limit of $D$?

Formally, this means that for some $Y\in{\mathscr C}$ you can check whether the natural morphism in $\textsf{Set}$,
$${\mathscr C}(Y,X)\to {\lim}_I{\mathscr C}(Y,D(i))$$
is an isomorphism. Call the respective subcategory ${\mathscr C}_D$ for lack of a better name. Now you have two facts:

1. Since inverse limits commute, ${\mathscr C}_D$ is closed under colimits in ${\mathscr C}$.
2. If $X$ and the codomain of $I$ are contained in some full subcategory ${\mathscr D}$ in which $X\to D$ is indeed an inverse limit, then ${\mathscr D}\subseteq{\mathscr C}_D$.

Combining both, it follows that ${\mathscr C}_D={\mathscr C}$ if there's a full subcategory ${\mathscr D}\subset{\mathscr C}$ containing $X$ and the codomain of $D$, for which $X\to D$ is a limit, and such that any object of ${\mathscr C}$ is a colimit of a diagram in ${\mathscr D}$.

This applies to $R\text{-mod}\subset R\text{-Mod}$ and shows that the latter embedding preserves all limits, in particular kernels.

Comment: What is the difference between $R-mod$ and $R-Mod$?

Comment: @gen $R\text{-mod}$ is the category of finitely generated $R$-modules, while $R\text{-Mod}$ is the category of all $R$-modules. The latter is always abelian, while the latter is if and only if $R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: aha! Thanks a lot for clarifying, I wasn't familiar with this notation

Comment: also I think your second 'latter' was meant to be 'former'